# Have fill-region break Python code into multiple lines to stay under 80 columns in Emacs

Tags: emacs, python, autoindent

How can I get Emacs' `indent-region` command to re-indent

```python
def foo():
    my_favorite_object_ever = ObjectConstructor(cool_parameter=4, not_cool_parameter=5)
```

as

```python
def foo():
    my_favorite_object_ever = ObjectConstructor(cool_parameter=4,
                                                not_cool_parameter=5)
```

when I'm working in Python mode?

Is there a way I can perhaps combine `fill-region` and `indent-region`?

**EDIT:**

So far I've got this Elisp code in my .emacs:

```elsip
(defun fill-indent-region (begin end)
  "Fill and then indent the code from BEGIN to END."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region begin end)
    (fill-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))))
```

It is a little buggy though.